# Change Combination Problem: I found this code, but I'm having trouble understanding some lines

Tags: python

I found this code (python) online and I get how some of the lines work. I'm still a beginner and I'm wondering how these lines work? Things like how range works, what the lines are doing, etcetera would be very appreciated! This code finds out the total number of combinations to  make change for a dollar.

```
combinations = [1]+[0]*change_needed

for type_of_coin in coins_used:
    for m in range(type_of_coin, change_needed+1):
        combinations[m] += combinations[m-type_of_coin]
```

Whole Code:

```
change_needed = 100
coins_used = [1, 5, 10, 25, 100,]

combinations = [1]+[0]*change_needed

for type_of_coin in coins_used:
    for m in range(type_of_coin, change_needed+1):
        combinations[m] += combinations[m-type_of_coin]

print('Total Number of Combinations:', combinations[change_needed])
```

Comment: Explore python documentation and experiment with the code some! Hands-on experience is better than some person telling you on the internet.

Comment: It's calculating the number of combinations using the recursion formula.

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr:** The replies are right: you should probably explore the Python documentation some -- it has many really useful examples and code explanations that will be of much use to you. Hands-on experience is better than someone on the internet telling you!

---

The general gist of this code is that it calculates the number of combinations possible to create a value of 100 units using only the values specified in `coins_used`: 1, 5, 10, 25, and 100.

Here's a commented explanation of the code (with some variable names changed for readability):

```py
# Necessary variables
change_needed = 100
coins_used = [1, 5, 10, 25, 100,]

# Creates an array called combinations...
combinations = (
  # ...containing an array with a single 1...
  [1]
  # ...concatenated with...
  +
  # ...an array with 0 indexed 100 times.
  [0] * 100
)
# This array will contain [1, 0, 0, 0, ... 0].

# This line iterates over the array coins_used: it will run once for 1, once for
# 5, once for 10... etc.
for coin_type in coins_used:
  # The range() function generates an array of numbers from the first variable
  # (start) to the last variable (stop). This array INCLUDES the start, but
  # EXCLUDES the stop. 
  #
  # This function is using range to create a list inbetween coin_type and
  # change_needed.
  for i in range(coin_type, change_needed + 1):
    # This changes the ith variable in the combinations array to the sum of its
    # current value and the (i - coin_type)th value.
    #
    # Remember that computers count starting at zero, so combinations[i] would
    # be the (i + 1)th item in the array!
    combinations[i] += combinations[i - coin_type]
# This entire loop is an example of the recursion formula.

# This line prints the total number of combinations, the last number in the
# array. Remember: computers count starting at zero, so this is item #101!
print('Total Number of Combinations:', combinations[change_needed])
```

---

*As an aside, I'd like to point out that your code is* **very** *inefficient: it allocates one extra item (the first item) to the array which is completely unused, it is poorly documented and formatted, and generally confusing to read. Generally, avoid doing things like this.*